# JQuery AJAX - Sending a JSONP form with attached files

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm working in a contact form for our clients that creates webpages with us with their own domain. We offer them a hosting and a web editor to create their websites. When they create a contact form in their websites, whoever that visit their websites and fills a form to contact them, it is sent to our platform and it sends a email to our client notifying him/her that someone filled his/her contact form.

To make it work, we are using a `jsonp` ajax call in our clients webpage to send the form to our platform, which performs the email template and sends the email.

The problem now is that our clients asked to add a `input` field type to allow whoever that visits their page to attach a file to the form, so they can see an attached file in the contact notification email, but I can't find a way to do it using `jsonp` because it uses `GET` method to create a crossdomain request and everthing I've serarched in Stackoverflow, talks about using a `POST` method to send files with a form and get form data as `new FormData()`.

Here is the code I had before trying the implementation:

```
var $form = $('form');
$form.submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: $form.serialize(),
        beforeSend: function () {
            $form.data('allowSending', false); // To prevent multiple sendings while processing
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data.message);
            $form.data('allowSending', true);
        }
    });
});
```

This is the code that I've tried, but it's not handled as expected:

```
var $form = $('form');
$form.submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: new FormData(this),
        beforeSend: function () {
            $form.data('allowSending', false); // To prevent multiple sendings while processing
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data.message);
            $form.data('allowSending', true);
        }
    });
});
```

When it sends the filled form with the code that I've tried (the second one), tries to send the data as an object through the URL, like: `?callback=jQuery111107622947758095266_1459251318335&[object%20FormData]&_=1459251318336`

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

PS: To make things harder, forms are completely dynamic, so if a solution is passing parameters manually, etc. it must be in a dynamic way with a `for` loop.

Comment: have you tried with type: "POST" ?

Comment: By default jQuery ajax send data using GET method change it to POST (in the second one)

Comment: @MineshPatel — `dataType: "jsonp",` forces GET and causes the `method` or `type` to be ignored.

Comment: @Quentin sounds good.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't.

Your attempt is failing because, since JSONP makes a GET request, `contentType` is ignored and `data` is treated as a string (since you said `processData: false`).

As you say, JSONP works by encoding everything in the URL. While it is possible to use [the File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/File) to read the content of the file and convert it into a base64 encoded string, that will exceed URL length limits for all but the smallest of files which makes it impractical.

Stop using JSONP. It is a, frankly dirty, hack that was used to sneak around the Same Origin Policy. We now have [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), which is a standard, non-hacky, highly flexible method to selectively disable the same origin policy. One of the advantages of its flexibility is that you can make cross-origin POST requests using it.

Comment: I've never used CORS to do a cross-origin request. Could you share an easy example? :) I'm using jQuery to do the AJAX calls, so I don't know if I would be able to use CORS within the framework.

Comment: @DaGLiMiOuX — Remove `dataType: "jsonp",` from your existing code. Every other change you need to make you need to make on the server. The documentation I linked to tells you what headers you need to set. If you are working in raw PHP, use the `header()` function.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using Symfony, not raw PHP

Comment: Yes, I will take a look into that and look at Symfony docs to see what they suggest. Thanks for everything :)